# Using context and "this" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that requires me to make cells in a table editable when the equivalent row in another table has been clicked.  The problem I am having is that I can't get it to only make a single row in the updateable table editable, instead it is making every cell of every row editable.

Here is a sample on jsfiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/z9qtH/24/

In this sample if you click "Row 1" in the table at the top, the first row of the table below should have the contents of its cells replaced with inputs. Instead, both rows in the bottom table are becoming editable.

**Code**

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="editable">Row 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="updateable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1 - 1</td>
        <td>1 - 2</td>
        <td>1 - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 - 1</td>
        <td>2 - 2</td>
        <td>2 - 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function replaceRowCellContentsWithInput(row) {
    $("td", row).each(function() {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td.editable").click(function() {
        var cell = $(this);
        var rowIndex = cell.parent().index();
        var table = $("table.updateable");

        replaceRowCellContentsWithInput(table.children(rowIndex));
    });
});
```

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line: `table.children(rowIndex)` selects the (possible `thead`) and `tbody` elements. Even if they do not appear in your HTML, the browser always inserts a `tbody`.

If you replace that with (for instance) `$('tr', table)[rowIndex]` you are sure you actually are selecting the rows inside the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this particular selector:

```
table.children(rowIndex)
```

Children returns the immediate child -- for `<table>` this is the `<tbody>`.

So when you use this as the context, your loop hits every `<td>` in your table, regardless of what row you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try replaceWith()...

just modified as per ur requirement
.......

```
 function replaceRowCellContentsWithInput(row) {
        $("td", row).each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
        });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9qtH/24/